# Complementary to Lyapunov Stability Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, lyapunov-functions

Lyapunov Stability Theorem states, loosely speaking, that for $x' = Ax + G(x,t)$ where $G(x, t) = o(\|x\|)$, if all eigenvalues of $A$ have **negative** real parts, then solution $x_0=0$ is asymptotically stable.

It seems obvious to me that if at least one eigenvalue has a **positive** real part, then $x_0 = 0$ is not asymptotically stable (since, again, we can simply ignore $G(x,t)$ when $x \to 0$). However, I wasn't able to find a reference. Is this statement true? Does it have a name?

Comment: Perhaps you can combine this with (or trace it back to) the Hartman-Grobman theorem that the solution of the non-linear solution is in most cases similar to the matrix exponential solution of the linearized system?

Comment: Thanks, that's probably it. Do I understand correctly that Lyapunov Theorem is a special case of Hartman-Grobman?

Comment: Essentially. You still need to prove the claim for linear systems, but that should be linear algebra and norm equivalence.

Comment: The reference: H.Khalil, Nonlinear systems, 3rd edition, theorem 4.7

Comment: @AVK, thank you! Do you know one for the infinite-dimensional case?